# Extrair coluna do arquivo csv por orientação a objetos

Tags: python

Extrai as linhas de um arquivo txt através da orientação a objetos, preciso utilizar a herança para extrair a coluna de um arquivo csv

```
%%writefile carros.csv
id,valor_venda,valor_manutencao,portas,pessoas,porta_malas
1,vhigh,med,2,2,small
2,med,vhigh,2,2,small
3,low,vhigh,2,2,small
4,low,high,2,2,small
5,low,high,2,2,small
6,low,high,4,4,big
7,low,high,4,4,big
8,low,med,2,2,small
9,low,med,2,2,small
10,low,med,2,2,small
11,low,med,4,4,big
12,low,low,2,2,small
13,low,low,4,4,small
14,low,low,4,4,me

%%writefile musica.txt
Roda Viva
Chico Buarque
Tem dias que a gente se sente
Como quem partiu ou morreu
A gente estancou de repente
Ou foi o mundo então que cresceu
A gente quer ter voz ativa
No nosso destino mandar
Mas eis que chega a roda viva
E carrega o destino pra lá
Roda mundo, roda-gigante
Roda moinho, roda pião
O tempo rodou num instante
Nas voltas do meu coração
A gente vai contra a corrente
Até não poder resistir
Na volta do barco é que sente
O quanto deixou de cumprir
Faz tempo que a gente cultiva
A mais linda roseira que há
Mas eis que chega a roda viva
E carrega a roseira pra lá
Roda mundo, roda-gigante
Roda moinho, roda pião



#classe pai 
class ArquivoTexto():
  def __init__(self,arquivo:str):
    self.arquivo=arquivo
    self.conteudo=self._extrair_conteudo()

  def _extrair_conteudo(self):
    conteudo=None
    with open(file=self.arquivo,mode='r',encoding='utf8') as arquivo:
      conteudo=arquivo.readlines()
      return conteudo
  def _extrair_linha(self,numero_linha:int):
   return self.conteudo[numero_linha-1]


#arquivo txt
arquivo_txt=ArquivoTexto(arquivo='./musica.txt')




#extraindo linha 1, retornando 'Roda Viva'
numero_linha=1
print(arquivo_txt._extrair_linha(numero_linha=numero_linha))


class Arquivo_csv(ArquivoTexto):
  def __init__(self, arquivo: str,indice_coluna:str):
      super().__init__(arquivo=arquivo) #herdando classe pai
  
  def extrair_colunas(self,indice_coluna:str): #preciso extrair o conteudo da coluna sem o cabeçalho
    colunas=list()
    for linha in self.conteudo:
        conteudo_linha=linha.strip().split(sep=',')
        colunas.append(conteudo_linha[indice_coluna])
        colunas.pop(0)
        return colunas






#arquivo_csv
arquivo_csv=Arquivo_csv(arquivo='./carros.csv')



coluna1=arquivo_csv.extrair_colunas(indice_coluna=3)

#traz o erro 'extrair_colunas() got an unexpected keyword argument 'indice_coluna'
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a trazer a coluna do arquivo csv herdando os atributos e métodos da casse ArquivoTXT?

Answer (score 0):

Para obter todos os valores dessa coluna temos de abrir o ficheiro CSV, separar as linhas, fazer um ciclo a começar no 2º índice para não incluir o cabeçalho e adicionar cada valor a uma lista que retornamos no fim.

```
class Arquivo_csv(ArquivoTexto):
  def __init__(self, arquivo: str):
      super().__init__(arquivo=arquivo) #herdando classe pai
  
  def extrair_colunas(self,indice_coluna:str): #preciso extrair o conteudo da coluna sem o cabeçalho
    conteudo = None
    with open(self.arquivo, "r") as f:
        conteudo=f.read().splitlines()
        valores = []
        for i in range(1, len(conteudo)):
            linha = conteudo[i]
            conteudo_linha=linha.strip().split(sep=',')
            valores.append(conteudo_linha[indice_coluna])
        
        return valores
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Deu certo.